# Vectorialize getting the min of elements in a position relative to the current element with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having a hard time vectorializing the following function:

```
def find_empty_square_sizes(matrix: np.ndarray):
    shape = matrix.shape
    res_matrix = np.ones(shape, dtype=np.int32)
    res_matrix[matrix != 0] = 0
    for i in range(1, shape[0]):
        for j in range(1, shape[1]):
            if matrix[i][j] == 1:
                res_matrix[i][j] = 0
            else:
                res_matrix[i][j] = np.min(np.ma.masked_array(res_matrix[i - 1:i + 1, j - 1:j + 1], mask=[[0, 0], [0, 1]])) + 1
    return res_matrix
```

The idea is to find the biggest square sub matrix of zeros inside a matrix. What the result, `res_matrix`, means is if the element on row i and column j was the bottom right corner of a sub matrix, how big that sub matrix could be while having only zeros.

Running for example the following code:

```
m = np.zeros((6, 6), dtype=np.int32)
m[2, 2] = 1
res = find_empty_square_sizes(m)
print(m)
print(res)
```

Yields the following results:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 2 2 2 2 2]
 [1 2 0 1 2 3]
 [1 2 1 0 1 2]
 [1 2 2 1 1 2]
 [1 2 3 2 2 2]]
```

I'm doing this for some image processing purposes and for HD images with over a thousand rows and columns this takes about a minute on my PC and I'd like to improve that. Any ideas on how to vectorialize the `find_empty_square_sizes` function or achieve a similar result through a more efficient method?

Comment: The data-dependencies between iterations make it very hard to vectorize with Numpy. One can try to vectorize the independent items on the diagonal but this is tricky to do and clearly sub-optimal (though probably better than the current code). Using Numba or Cython can help to strongly improve performance without the need to change significantly the code. Is this Ok for you?

Comment: I'm aware but not too familiar with them, but now seems like a good time to change that. I'll see if I can get significant speed ups that way, thanks for the tip

Comment: @JérômeRichard Finally tried Cython after putting this on hold for a couple weeks and execution got over a 1000x faster, quite impressive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this with a similar problem, following Jerome Richard's advice I used Cython and the following code brought down the execution time from a minute to about 40 ms, quite a difference!

```
#cython: language_level=3

import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)


def find_empty_square_sizes(matrix: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    res_matrix = np.ones((matrix.shape[0], matrix.shape[1]), dtype=np.int32)
    res_matrix[matrix != 0] = 0
    _find_empty_square_sizes(matrix, res_matrix, matrix.shape[0], matrix.shape[1])
    return res_matrix


cdef _find_empty_square_sizes(int[:, :] matrix, int[:, :] res_matrix, int x, int y):
    cdef int i
    cdef int j

    for i in range(1, x):
        for j in range(1, y):
            if matrix[i][j] == 1:
                res_matrix[i][j] = 0
            else:
                res_matrix[i][j] = _min(res_matrix[i - 1, j - 1], res_matrix[i, j - 1], res_matrix[i - 1, j]) + 1


cdef _min(int a, int b, int c):
    cdef int min = a
    if b < min:
        min = b
    if c < min:
        min = c
    return min
```